# How does ember-tooltips decide where to put the tooltip in the DOM?

Tags: ember.js

I have the problem that mostly `ember-tooltips` does attach the tooltip to the `<body>`, but in some cases it's exactly where I've put `{{#tooltip-on-element}}`.

How can I control this behavior? I want to always have it in the `<body>` to prevent different styling from my `CSS`.

Comment: It is attached wherever you put `{{#tooltip-on-element}}`. For example you can put all tooltips on top of the page and set `target` for each to attach to the element

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani nope. For like 80% of my tooltips its attached directly in the `<body>`. I just dont understand why.